# Issue in function pointer

Tags: c++, function-pointers, pointer-to-member

In a.hpp file

```
class trees
{
    public:
        virtual void func();
    private:
        void world(uint8_t alpha, uint8_t beta);
}
```

In a.cpp

```
#include "a.hpp"
void trees::world(uint8_t alpha, uint8_t beta)
{
    
}
void trees::func()
{
    hello( hi, world ); //error
}
```

where `hello` and `plant` are as follows in a separate file:

```
int hello(struct b* c, plant d);  
typedef void plant(uint8_t alpha, uint8_t beta);
```

The 2<sup>nd</sup> argument gives error saying that `(tress::*) is not compatible with parameter of type world`

I understand I need to instantiate the obj but I do not know how to do it.

Comment: @churill "hello(hi,world) is called inside a function. I have edited the question. Does it make sense now?

Comment: `hello` isn't a member of `tree`, therefore it doesn't know about other `tree` members, like `tree::world`. Furthermore, (non-static) member functions are ***not*** equal to non-member functions. A member function needs an object to be called on, which a non-member function doesn't. That makes a very big difference.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I was wrong, I just edited the question

Answer (score 0):

Function pointers are not the same thing as member function pointers.

This code will compile

```
class trees
{
    public:
       void world(uint8_t alpha, uint8_t beta);
};

typedef void (trees::*plant)(uint8_t alpha, uint8_t beta);

int hello(struct b* c, plant d);

void func()
{
    b* hi = ...;
    hello(hi, &trees::world);
}
```

However you still need a `trees` object in order to call the method your method function pointer is pointing at. There's nothing in your posted code to indicate where that is coming from.

Assuming that `p` is a pointer to a `trees` object then the syntax to call the method using the pointer `d` is `(p->*d)(1, 2);`

Comment: typedef void (trees::*plant)(uint8_t alpha, uint8_t beta); - This is a non changeable line for me. It is coming from a device driver. So I will not be able to change it

Comment: @galaxy2096 Then you cannot pass a non-static member function to your routine. Function pointers and member function pointers are not compatible. A static member function would be OK.

Comment: Actually func is a public method in trees class, I just edited the question

Comment: @galaxy2096 OK but that doesn't change the basic problem.

Comment: @galaxy2096 The typical solution would be to change the `world` method to be `static` and from that static method call a non-static method. That requires that you save a pointer to a `trees` object somewhere. Worst case is that you create a global variable for that purpose.

Comment: static void world(uint8_t alpha, uint8_t beta);  - I just did this and the error is gone. Is this enough? I did not understand the part where you said saving a pointer to a trees object

Comment: @galaxy2096 It depends on what you want to do inside `world`. Presumably it is part of the `trees` class for a reason. Does it need to access any member variables? Or member functions? As a static meothd it won't be able to do either without a `trees` object somewhere. But if it doesn't need to do that then no problem (although then I would be wondering why `world` is a member of `trees` at all).

Comment: Yes, there is another method called func2() which is private in trees. Now in order to access that, I created a local object of trees inside world and called func2(). Would it better to declare inside the world or outside the world?

Answer (score 0):

Pointer to member is a very different beast because it must be bound to a *specific instance* so that you can access that instance's members, as each object may have different member offsets (for properties) and different methods (for virtual methods). A static method OTOH is exactly like a global function, just in a different namespace so you don't need an object to call it. Therefore if you don't need to access any private members then just use a static member

```
static void world(uint8_t alpha, uint8_t beta);
```

If you really need to access the private members then there are several ways without changing the signature:

- Declare `world` as a friend function
- Use [std::bind](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind)

  ```
  trees tree; // the tree instance
  auto plant = std::bind(&trees::world, &tree, _1, _2);
  ```

  Then `plant(alpha, beta)` will be the same as `(tree.*world)(alpha, beta);`

> ## Is the type of “pointer-to-member-function” different from “pointer-to-function”?
>
> Yep.
>
> Consider the following function:
>
> ```
> int f(char a, float b);
> ```
>
> The type of this function is different depending on whether it is an ordinary function or a non-static member function of some class:
>
> - Its type is `int (*)(char,float)` if an ordinary function
> - Its type is `int (Fred::*)(char,float)` if a non-static member function of class Fred
>
> Note: if it’s a static member function of class Fred, its type is the same as if it were an ordinary function: `int (*)(char,float)`.
>
> https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/pointers-to-members#fnptr-vs-memfnptr-types